# Django EmailMultiAlternatives - When attach a file: Body becomes blank in email

Tags: python, django

I use EmailMultiAlternatives to send mail in my django application. Please find below code for reference:

```
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject,
        body=body_text,
        from_email=from_email,
        to=to_email,
        reply_to=reply_to_email,
        cc=cc_email,
        bcc=bcc_email
    )
    email.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')

    # attachments
    for attachment in attachments:
        email.attach(attachment.name, attachment.document.read())

    email.send()
```

Now problem is whenever there is any attachment, email body gets blank. Is there any conflict between attach_alternative and attach.
Let me know if any doubt/confusion! Thanks

Comment: maybe it has something to do with this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26344

Comment: right @daigorocub , I solve this issue by using striptags(body_html) in body. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue got resolved by striptags

from django.template.defaultfilters import striptags

````
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject,
        body=body_text or striptags(body_html),
        from_email=from_email,
        to=to_email,
        reply_to=reply_to_email,
        cc=cc_email,
        bcc=bcc_email
    )
    email.attach_alternative(body_html, 'text/html')

    # attachments
    for attachment in attachments:
        email.attach(attachment.name, attachment.document.read())

    email.send()```
````

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed in more recent django versions. I'm using a older version and fixed it by applying a patch to django/core/mail/message.py with the correction:

```
--- message.py  2020-08-11 09:37:27.000000000 +0100
+++ message2.py 2020-08-11 09:36:26.000000000 +0100
@@ -409,7 +409,7 @@
             encoding = self.encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
             body_msg = msg
             msg = SafeMIMEMultipart(_subtype=self.mixed_subtype, encoding=encoding)
-            if self.body:
+            if self.body or body_msg.is_multipart():
                 msg.attach(body_msg)
             for attachment in self.attachments:
                 if isinstance(attachment, MIMEBase):
```